# Duplicate data displaying in report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

My code displays data on a datagridview and a report. Why do I get duplicate entries in the report when the datagridview properly shows a single entry?

[image]

[image]

```
Private Sub Butt_searchInvoice(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Butt_searchInvoice.Click
    connect() 
        sql = "select  distinct SALESINVOice.[Invoice NO],[Invoice Date], " _
        & "[Customer Name], Productname,Qty,Rate,amount from salesinvoice " _
        & " inner join salesinvoicedetails on SALESINVOICE.[Invoice NO]= " _
        & " salesinvoicedetails.[Invoice No] " _
        & "where salesinvoice.[Invoice NO]   = '" & txt_invoiceNO.Text & "' "
        objcmd = New SqlCommand(sql, objcon)
        objda.SelectCommand = objcmd
        Dim ds as new dataset
        objda.Fill(ds, "stt")

        ''displaying in datagridview
        DataGridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables("stt")

        ''displaying Data in Crystal report
        Dim Path as new SalesInvoicerpt()
        Path.Load(Application.StartupPath + "C:\SalesInvoicerpt.rpt")
        Path.SetDataSource(ds.Tables("stt"))
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Path
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()        
        objcon .Close 
End Sub
```

Comment: Both invoice numbers are 50. So each Invoice 50 in salesinvoice is going to match to both invoices in the other table. Do you have something more unique in both tables? Maybe link on invoice number AND customer name? Although I doubt customer name is in both

Comment: There is unique [invoice No] in the SalesInvoice Table.  and my SalesOrderDetail Table have a column for an [Invoice NO] .  This makes it possible to associate an order with one or more Sales order Details.

Comment: and there is only one invoice 50 in the salesInvoice Table.  but there is two 50 in the SAlesOrderDetails Table they are the foreign keys so  they reference the  SalesInvoice Table. each invoice no can contain many item s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your section expert and highlight group 3 details. Next to your suppression formula entry add this formula.
[image]

```
{SALESINVOice.Productname}=previous({SALESINVOice.Productname})
```

Comment: thnx alotttt Justin Woodmancy. it fixed my issue with the report.thnx alot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Go back to your Crystal Report: right click the field which is duplicate then,

Do it like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried that But it gives me  an empty record's row.

Comment: and if there is two items which have same Quantity it suppresses on of them and it gives me an empty row

Comment: When i run the query in SQL server it shows no duplicates and i get the results that i want. But when i write the same Statement to display data on the crystal report it shows duplicates  i don't know why this happens?